# Is there a name for the repetition of lyrics in music by a person or group of persons?

Tags: voice, terminology

In the song [BrokEn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OgVs4N1Mkk) by Coldplay there are lyrics sung by the lead singer that are repeated by a background choir;

```
Lord, when I'm broken (when I'm broken)
I'm in need (I'm in need)
I feel that ocean (feel that ocean)
Swallowing me (swallowing me)
```

It reminds me of Gospel music. Is there a name for this kind of back-and-forth in music? Or are there genres in which this occurs often?

Comment: The general technique is "call and response". I don't know if there's a more specific term when the call and the response are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Call and response* or *antiphony* means some kind of trading of musical statements back and forth between players or ensembles.

But when you mention repetition of lyrics you probably should also know the term *refrain* which is a stanza or line of poetry (lyrics) repeated, like the title in the song *The Times They Are A-Changin*.

Call and response in most cases probably won't involve a refrain. Call and response is usually the immediate repetition of a line or maybe just involves new lines. But, immediate repetition doesn't make a refrain. A refrain is more structural a stanza or ending line of a stanza that is usually repeated in some regular pattern.

I would call your example *call and response.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a musical trick to emulate an **echo**. I would argue it's not a call/response, since the response would typically be different from the call.